# Saving an AI file in Illustrator automatically generates a PDF

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, save

When I save an AI file in Illustrator, I usually keep the default "Save As" Illustrator settings. My understanding is, that when you save an AI file, it automatically generates a PDF version as well. Where can this PDF version be accessed? I am never able to access it on my computer or in Illustrator. I know it "buckets" the two together, but, I simply don't see it. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

By default Illustrator creates a PDF Compatible File. Not a PDF file. The default settings will create a .ai file. The .ai file that it creates, when "Create PDF compatible file" is checked is then able to be opened by Acrobat and viewed as a PDF.

[image: Default Options]